# php scandir() not showing files - only showing directories

Tags: php, scandir

I have a directory structure as follows:

> /files 
>   /files/001 
>   /files/001/addfile.php 
>   /files/002 
>   /files/002/deletefile.php 
>   /files/003 
>   /files/003/viewfile.php

My script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$directory      = 'files';
$files      = scandir($directory);

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xmlFiles = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('FILES'));
if(is_dir($directory)) {
    print_r($files);
}
/*foreach($files as $file => $key) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') { continue; }
    echo '$file: '.$file;
    if(is_dir("$directory/$file")) {
        $xmlDir->appendChild($xml->createElement($file));
    }
    else {
        $xmlFiles->appendChild($xml->createElement('FILE', $file));
    }
}*/
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

My problem: The `print_r($files)` outputs:

> Array (
>       [0] => .
>       [1] => ..
>       [2] => 001
>       [3] => 002
>       [4] => 003 )

How come scandir only outputs the directories and not the files?

TIA,
Nate

Comment: The index number of each array element:
$file: 0$file: 1$file: 2$file: 3$file: 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scandir does not work recursively. It only scans the path input into it.

[Scandir Recurrsive function to scan deeper into the file system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#109140)

Comment: I am really wondering why, after almost 3 years you decided to revoke your approval of my answer and accepted your own. It will not give you any reputation points, not to mention you are not looking much serious

Answer (score 5):

your files are in these directories,  and scandir shows just content of specified path,  but without any recurrency,  so all is correct.

Comment: so scandir doesn't go any deeper into the directory structure? eg past /files

Answer (score 2):

you can use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` for get directory with sub directory listing

Here is how to empty a directory using iterator:

```
<?php
function empty_dir($dir) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
                                             RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
   foreach ($iterator as $path) {
     if ($path->isDir()) {
        // do something with directory
        //    rmdir($dir);
     } else {
       //doo something with files 
       // unlink($path->__toString());
     }
   }
  //    rmdir($dir);
}
?>
```