# Scandir not listing files when remote

Tags: php

I'm working on an image compression cron job for my sites assets. The problem I'm facing is that the code works fine locally but not on on the remote server.

I'm using `scandir`, I've seen the related post: [php scandir() not showing files - only showing directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557502/php-scandir-not-showing-files-only-showing-directories) users were saying that it isn't recursive. However on my local system I've replicated the folder structure on the remote server and it works perfectly.

I have the following function which I use for both folders and files.

```
function getFilesInDir($path)
{
    $directory = $path;
    if (is_dir($directory))
    {
        $files = array();
        foreach(scandir($directory) as $file)
        {
            if ('.' === $file) continue;
            if ('..' === $file) continue;
            $files[] = $file;

            // }

        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

When I use `var_dump` on the the folder I get the right results. It lists all folders within the specified directory.

**Usage**

```
$folders = getFilesInDir("site/assets/files");

foreach($folders as $folder)
{
    $files = getFilesInDir($folder);
    //...Do the rest
```

So `var_dump($folders)` displays the correct directories. When I do `var_dump($files)` I get `NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL`.

I reiterate, this works fine on my local machine but not my remote server.

**Complete Code (if it's of use)**
It's not pretty I know but it works and I'm on a deadline.

```
<?php

// $folders = getFilesInDir(getcwd());

$folders = getFilesInDir("site/assets/files");

foreach($folders as $folder)
{
    $files = getFilesInDir($folder);
    var_dump($files);
    if ($files)
    {
        $x = array_filter($files, "isImage");
        foreach($files as $f)
        {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($f);
            if (@$path_parts['extension'] != null)
            {
                if (filesize($folder . "/" . $f) > 1000000)
                {
                    echo $f . " - " . filesize($folder . "/" . $f) . "<br />";
                    if ($path_parts['extension'] == "jpg" || $path_parts['extension'] == 

"jpeg" || $path_parts['extension'] == "png")
                    {

                        // Make bin folder if not exists

                        MakeFolder($folder . "/");

                        // Compress file in folder to bin folder

                        $d = compress($folder . "/" . $f, $folder . "/bin/" . $f, 30);

                        // Delete files in base

                        unlink($folder . "/" . $f);

                        // Move files from bin to root

                        rename($folder . "/bin/" . $f, $folder . "/" . $f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function MakeFolder($path)
{
    if (!file_exists($path . "/bin/"))
    {
        mkdir($path . "/bin/", 0777, true);
    }
}

function isImage($var)
{
    $path_parts = pathinfo($var);
    if (@$path_parts['extension'])
    {
        if ($path_parts['extension'] == "jpg" || $path_parts['extension'] == "jpeg" || $path_parts

['extension'] == "png")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function getFilesInDir($path)
{
    $directory = $path;
    if (is_dir($directory))
    {
        $files = array();
        foreach(scandir($directory) as $file)
        {
            if ('.' === $file) continue;
            if ('..' === $file) continue;
            $files[] = $file;

            // }

        }
    }

    return $files;
}

function compress($source, $destination, $quality)
{
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scandir` only returns the filenames **without path**. You need to append the path of the original folder to the new one's.

```
$path = "site/assets/files"
$folders = getFilesInDir($path);

foreach($folders as $folder)
{
    $files = getFilesInDir($path . "/" . $folder);
    var_dump($files);
```

Hope this does it.

Comment: Oh god, you're right. How did I miss that. Thanks skreborn.